# System stops session seamingly at random

Tags: xorg, kde

A few times a day, I´d say three times on average, my system crashes and stops the session. There is no (to me) indication of why this happens, it seems to do so randomly. All  drivers are up-to-date and no additional drivers are available and no proprietary drivers are used. After the crash I can simply login again, but a new session will start.

I am using a Thinkpad X1 carbon gen 9, with **Ubuntu 22.04** and **KDE plasma on X.** This is my system information:

`Linux dx1 5.15.0-40-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 15 12:54:21 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

And these are logfiles form the `syslog` around the time of the latest crash:

```
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 systemd-oomd[795]: Killed /system.slice/mariadb.service due to memory used (14920273920) / total (16486973440) and swap used (1027600384) / total (1027600384) being more than 90.00%
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 pulseaudio[42991]: ICE I/O error handler called
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 at-spi-bus-launcher[42843]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: systemd-oomd killed 5 process(es) in this unit.
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Consumed 6.450s CPU time.
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 sddm[1063]: Authentication error: "Process crashed"
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 sddm[1063]: Auth: sddm-helper crashed (exit code 9)
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 sddm[1063]: Authentication error: "Process crashed"
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 sddm[1063]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 9
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 sddm[1063]: Socket server stopping...
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 sddm[1063]: Socket server stopped.
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 sddm[1063]: Display server stopping...
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 systemd[1855]: app-org.kde.kate-796166c415a84c73a7081705b945673e.scope: Consumed 1.943s CPU time.
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 kglobalaccel5[42906]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 kactivitymanagerd[42959]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 kscreen_backend_launcher[43163]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 baloorunner[69620]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 xdg-desktop-portal-kde[44703]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 systemd[1855]: plasma-kglobalaccel.service: Consumed 1.551s CPU time.
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 systemd[1855]: plasma-kscreen.service: Consumed 1.496s CPU time.
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 systemd[1855]: app-org.kde.kate-41de09ef41b3486cb72d187fa9cf7f9e.scope: Consumed 8.088s CPU time.
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 systemd[1855]: plasma-kactivitymanagerd.service: Consumed 1.693s CPU time.
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 systemd[1855]: plasma-xdg-desktop-portal-kde.service: Consumed 1.979s CPU time.
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_hq
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_sq
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_mq
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx_hd
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_hd
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Jul  1 16:55:58 dx1 bluetoothd[877]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.732 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 systemd[1855]: pulseaudio.service: Consumed 5min 19.273s CPU time.
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 systemd[1]: session-26.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 systemd[1]: session-26.scope: Consumed 3h 35min 49.929s CPU time.
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.087408] evdi: [I] (card4) Closed by Task 42468 (Xorg) of process 42468 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.087415] evdi: [I] (card3) Closed by Task 42468 (Xorg) of process 42468 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.087417] evdi: [I] (card2) Closed by Task 42468 (Xorg) of process 42468 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.087419] evdi: [I] (card1) Closed by Task 42468 (Xorg) of process 42468 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 sddm[1063]: Display server stopped.
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 sddm[1063]: Running display stop script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xstop"
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 sddm[1063]: Removing display ":0" ...
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 sddm[1063]: Adding new display on vt 1 ...
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 sddm[1063]: Loading theme configuration from ""
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 sddm[1063]: Display server starting...
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 sddm[1063]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{c3af04c5-d207-423e-9ce7-6e827bbfc4f9}"
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 sddm[1063]: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{c3af04c5-d207-423e-9ce7-6e827bbfc4f9} -background none -noreset -displayfd 18 -seat seat0 vt1
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.117527] evdi: [I] (card1) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg.wrap) of process 85345 (Xorg.wrap)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.117536] evdi: [I] (card1) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg.wrap) of process 85345 (Xorg.wrap)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.117539] evdi: [I] (card2) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg.wrap) of process 85345 (Xorg.wrap)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.117541] evdi: [I] (card2) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg.wrap) of process 85345 (Xorg.wrap)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.117543] evdi: [I] (card3) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg.wrap) of process 85345 (Xorg.wrap)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.117545] evdi: [I] (card3) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg.wrap) of process 85345 (Xorg.wrap)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.117548] evdi: [I] (card4) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg.wrap) of process 85345 (Xorg.wrap)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.117550] evdi: [I] (card4) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg.wrap) of process 85345 (Xorg.wrap)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.134495] evdi: [I] (card1) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.134502] evdi: [I] (card1) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.134570] evdi: [I] (card2) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.134573] evdi: [I] (card2) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.134638] evdi: [I] (card3) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.134641] evdi: [I] (card3) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.134705] evdi: [I] (card4) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.134708] evdi: [I] (card4) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.151648] evdi: [I] (card1) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.151659] evdi: [I] (card1) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.151671] evdi: [I] (card2) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.151674] evdi: [I] (card2) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.151683] evdi: [I] (card3) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.151686] evdi: [I] (card3) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.151695] evdi: [I] (card4) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.151699] evdi: [I] (card4) Closed by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.297564] evdi: [I] (card1) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.308827] evdi: [I] (card2) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.313523] evdi: [I] (card3) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:55:59 dx1 kernel: [31600.318706] evdi: [I] (card4) Opened by Task 85345 (Xorg) of process 85345 (Xorg)
Jul  1 16:56:00 dx1 sddm[1063]: Setting default cursor
Jul  1 16:56:00 dx1 sddm[1063]: Running display setup script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup"
Jul  1 16:56:00 dx1 sddm[1063]: Display server started.
Jul  1 16:56:00 dx1 sddm[1063]: Socket server starting...
Jul  1 16:56:00 dx1 sddm[1063]: Socket server started.

I am hoping someone can help me figure out what might be causing this issue and how to solve it.
```

Comment: you're running low on memory apparently, if `oomd` is killing processes.

Comment: I expect that the logs from a few lines earlier would show xorg getting killed by oomd or something similar. It appears xorg is getting killed (but no logs of it directly, maybe there are logs somewhere else), and also mariadb is getting killed by oomd

Comment: how much memory do you have?

Comment: there is 16gb of memory